# listen to two websockets at the same time with asyncio

Tags: python, asynchronous, websocket, python-asyncio

I' trying to listen to two websockets at the same time with asyncio. This doesn't work. How can I do this?

I want to get whichever messages comes first, and print it out.

```
async with websockets.connect(sock_uri_1) as w1, \
            websockets.connect(sock_uri_2) as w2:

        msg1 = ensure_future(w1.recv())
        msg2 = ensure_future(w2.recv())
        while True:
            if msg1.done():
               print(msg1.result())
               msg1 = ensure_future(w1.recv())
            if msg2.done():
               print(msg1.result())
               msg2 = ensure_future(w2.recv())
            time.sleep(1) # Want to avoid this!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should use `await asyncio.sleep(1)` rather than `time.sleep(1)`. Your approach can work without sleeping by using `asyncio.wait(when_done=FIRST_COMPLETED)` to wait for one (or both) of the messages to arrive:

```
async with websockets.connect(sock_uri_1) as w1, \
            websockets.connect(sock_uri_2) as w2:
    msg1 = ensure_future(w1.recv())
    msg2 = ensure_future(w2.recv())
    while True:
        await asyncio.wait([msg1, msg2], when_done=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
        if msg1.done():
           print(msg1.result())
           msg1 = ensure_future(w1.recv())
        if msg2.done():
           print(msg1.result())
           msg2 = ensure_future(w2.recv())
```

I find managing explicit tasks somewhat tedious, especially when the number of sources can vary. In this case I'd use a queue to combine the messages into a single channel:

```
async with websockets.connect(sock_uri_1) as w1, \
            websockets.connect(sock_uri_2) as w2:
    channel = asyncio.Queue()
    async def transmit(w, source):
        while True:
            msg = await w.recv()
            await channel.put((source, msg))
    asyncio.create_task(transmit(w1, 'source1')
    asyncio.create_task(transmit(w2, 'source2')
    while True:
        source, msg = await channel.get()
        if source == 'source1':
            print(sock_uri_1, msg)
        elif source == 'source2':
            print(sock_uri_2, msg)
```

Comment: @siamii You would use them to cancel the tasks (by calling `t1.cancel()` and `t2.cancel()`) if you wanted to break out of the loop. But since your loop is infinite, they ended up being unused so I've now removed them.